# How can I reshape a Function?

Tags: function-construction

Following function is given.

```
y[x_]:=2*x
```

Now I need to reshape this function so that I get x dependent of y. So I should get a function like this:

```
x[y_]:=y/2
```

How can I use Mathematic to do this reshaping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_] := 2*x
```

Use [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html)

```
InverseFunction[f][y]

(*  y/2  *)
```